# How to Open database connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am working on login by following this article [Creating a custom user login form with .NET C# MVC 4 Razor](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/482546/Creating-a-custom-user-login-form-with-NET-Csharp)

So in that I have followed all those steps as mentioned I that article now form that I am fetching the problem with open database connection..

**In Models**

```
public class User
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public boolRememberMe { get; set; }

    public bool IsValid(string _username, string _password)
    {
        using (var conn = newSqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDBFilename='E:\\TodayData\\DatabaseLogin\\LoginExample\\LoginExample\\App_Data\\DatabaseLoginExample.mdf';Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
        {
            string _sql = "SELECT [Username] FROM [dbo].[LoginInformation] WHERE [Username] = @u AND [Password] = @p";
            var cmd = newSqlCommand(_sql, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(newSqlParameter("@u", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = _username;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(newSqlParameter("@p", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = SHA1.Encode(_password);

            conn.Open();

            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                reader.Dispose();
                cmd.Dispose();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                reader.Dispose();
                cmd.Dispose();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In **conn.Open()** I am getting this Error

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>
> SqlException Was Unhandeled by User Code..

Can anyone help me to solve this

Comment: The database you are using stored in the same application?

Comment: "The server was not found or was not accessible." - I think that you are pointing to wrong location for your data source or data file and I would skip the problem with accessing the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify your connection string with the following code:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDBFilename='E:\TodayData\DatabaseLogin\LoginExample\LoginExample\App_Data\DatabaseLoginExample.mdf';Integrated Security=True"))
```

Comment: Now getting this Error,**E:\TodayData\DatabaseLogin\LoginExample\LoginExample\App_Data\DatabaseLoginExample.mdf failed.**